# Disappearing Intent data

Tags: android-intent, uri

So I have a uri in my main activity that I set to send to another intent using [intent_name].setData(uriVar); and by the time I need to extract the uri in the new activity using getIntent().getData() the uri becomes null. I pass uri's under several circumstances in my app and for some reason this is the only one where the object ends up null;

Setting the uri to the intent

```
        //add to gallery
        Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
        mediaScanIntent.setData(mMediaUri);
        sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
    }

    //Sends the Uri to the recipients page
    Intent recipientsIntent = new Intent(this, RecipientsActivity.class);
    Log.i(TAG, mMediaUri+ "");
    recipientsIntent.setData(mMediaUri);
```

I run this line and it logs that all the necessary data is there

```
Log.i(TAG, recipientsIntent.getData() + "");
            startActivity(recipientsIntent);
```

By the time we get here the data's gone. Logically there should be nothing erasing the data right? I'm pulling my hair out trying to understand.

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_recipients);

        mMediaUri = getIntent().getData();
```

Comment: Can you please share the code which sets the uri in the intent?

Comment: @PrerakSola yeah editing the post now

Comment: It's weird because I set the uri for when I take a photo and it works fine, but when I take a video which is essentially all the same code give or take a few lines that I've already thoroughly combed over